# Symfony: After login doesn't redirect back to requested page

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, referer

I want to redirect back to requested page after login, I know symfony provides that by default, but it's not working in my case. I have tried with `referer: true` in **security.yml** but didn't get any result.

I am using FOSUserBundle for User management.
Your help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**security.yml**

```
security:
 encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
    Admin\UserBundle\Entity\SuperAdmin: bcrypt
  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_DEFAULT:     ROLE_DEFAULT
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
  providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
    fos_userbundle:
      id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
    administrators:
        entity: { class: Admin\UserBundle\Entity\SuperAdmin, property: email}
  firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    social:
        pattern: ^/            
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
            default_target_path: user_bundle_homepage
            success_handler: my.authentication_success_handler
        logout:
            path:   fos_user_security_logout
            target: fos_user_security_login
        anonymous: true

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https  }        
    - { path: ^/login/facebook$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/login/google$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https  }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/admin0rama/.*, role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, requires_channel: https}
    - { path: ^/.*, role: ROLE_DEFAULT, requires_channel: https}
```

Comment: did you try with 'always_use_default_target_path: false' in your 'form_login' ?

Comment: @TimZwinkels I have tried with `always_use_default_target_path: false` but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to use `use_referer: true` in your firewall definition (not just `referer`).

Example:

```
# security.yaml
security:
    firewalls:
        social:
            form_login:
                use_referer: true
```

[The documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login.html#using-the-referring-url).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the _target_path, you can add this field to your login form, this works always for me in my projects

```
{% if app.request.get('_route') != app.request.headers.get('referer') %}    
    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ app.request.headers.get('referer') }}" />    
{% endif %}
```

I hope this can help you

[How to Customize Redirect After Form Login](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/form_login.html)